# setShadowLayer in app widget?

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to do this programatically so that the use has the option in include shadow or not in an app widget TextView?

I am only aware of that you can set a int but the setShadowLayer method takes several parameters....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, setShadowLayer() can't be called through the RemoveViews class used by a widget. However, in your case one solution would be to define 2 TextViews for each TextView that you want to be able to set a shadow on. One TextView will have the shadow and the other won't. Then during the initialisation of the widget hide the corresponding TextView according to your user's preference.

Comment: How would I do this in a RemoteViews?

Comment: @timothyjc Sorry I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer with one approach you can take.